# How to restore User account In Zimbra Admin console

Tags: email, server, zimbra

I didn't mean to do delete user but how to restore user in admin console please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily if you already have backup of mailbox,then just login to Zimbra admin console and right click on account for which you want to restore the data.After that go to import/export form here you can import user's mailbox.